# overloading operator<< for use with ostream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cppunit

I am using CPPUnit to test a class in my program.  This class (`SCriterionVal`) is somewhat unique because it has conversion operators for a lot of types (it's essentially a dynamic type value class).  When I compile test cases that test it using `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL()`, I get compilation errors about "`operator<<` is ambiguous" from one of the CPPUnit header files.  It appears that it is instantiating the `assertion_traits` struct with my type, and that struct has a `toString()` method that works by using `operator<<` on an `OStringStream`.

I assume it's ambiguous instead of an error because of the various conversions available on `SCriterionVal`, some of which have defined `operator<<` (such as the built in types).  In an attempt to rectify this situation, I created a non-member function in the header for `SCriterionVal` with this signature:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, SCriterionVal val);
```

I figured because the signature should be an exact match, it will resolve the ambiguity.  No such luck.  What am I doing wrong here?  I suppose I can specialize the template for `assertion_traits` for my type, but I was hoping to be able to solve the more general problem of providing a way to put my class into a stream, rather than just catering to the test framework.

Comment: Another case of an English description being sooo much better than code.

Comment: I think we should create another tag EBTC (Engish is Better Then Code)

Comment: Martin, I assume your comments are sarcastic.  I can't post the code because it's against my company's policy to do so.  Also, it's a very large class and uses dozens of custom types, so you wouldn't be able to compile it anyways.

Comment: A minimal example would be helpful. Change the names, remove stuff that isn't relevant, etc.

Comment: When you find yourself banging your head against some problem for a while, try to create a repro: Copy as much of the code as you need to get the unexpected behavior you're seeing. Then start to strip that copy down of as much seemingly unrelated code as possible, always trying whether the behavior is still the same. (Binary approximation works great there.) Often you'll find the error yourself doing so. If you don't, you end up with a great repro to post somewhere and ask: _"Why?"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining `operator<<` as a friend inline function inside the class definition. I always find this way works the best, especially for templates.

For example, Boost.Random defines `operator<<` inside `exponential distribution`'s declaration:

```
  template<class CharT, class Traits>
  friend std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&
  operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os, const exponential_distribution& ed)
  {
    os << ed._lambda;
    return os;
  }
```

Comment: this is an interesting technique I haven't seen before.  Is the function actually a method, or is it still a function not attached to an object (I don't know a term for that)?  I'm compiling with the changes now, so I'll let you know how it goes...

Comment: @meador: The `friend` can take a function definition instead of a declaration. That might seem strange (it certainly does to me), but that's just the way it is. The defined function is still a free function, even though it's defined inside the class.

Comment: I tried it with your templatized basic_ostream return type and it complained that my function was a void function returning a value.  I'm guessing that has to do with the fact that my compiler is MSVC++ 6.  I recoded it with just "ostream" instead of the template and I still get the ambiguity error I originally had.  I'm giving up... I'll give you a +1 under the assumption that your answer will help someone with a reasonable compiler.

Comment: MSVC++6 would be why it doesn't work. It doesn't support template overload resolution very well, so you are probably encountering the simple problem that the compiler sucks.